# Bubble sort in C showing segmentation fault

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I am writing a code to sort an array using bubble sort, but it is showing an error which I am unable to resolve. the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap();
void bubbleSort();
void printArr();

void main()
{
    int n, arr[20];
    printf("\n Enter the number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n Enter the elements: ");
    for(int i = 0; i<= n-1; i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[n]);
    bubbleSort(arr, n);
    printArr(arr, n);  
}

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void bubbleSort(int arr[], int size)
{
    int a, b;
    for(int i=0; i<=size-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[a] > arr[b])
            swap(arr[a],arr[b]);

    }
 }

void printArr(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    printf("\n Sorted array: ");
    for(i=0; i<=size-1; i++)
        printf(" %d ", arr[i]);
}
```

when i am compiling the file its showing two warnings like this:

sort.c: In function ‘bubbleSort’:

sort.c:37:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘swap’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

```
         swap(arr[a],arr[b]);
              ~~~^~~
```

sort.c:20:16: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

```
          void swap(int *a, int *b)
                    ~~~~~^
```

sort.c:37:28: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘swap’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

```
         swap(arr[a],arr[b]);
                     ~~~^~~
```

sort.c:20:24: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’

```
         void swap(int *a, int *b)
                   ~~~~~^
```

when I am running the program it is taking the input but after that its showing `segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the closing `'}'` to `bubbleSort`?? (was that a simple typo?)

Comment: The warnings speak for themselves, read them carefully.

Comment: Those parameter-less declarations ask for trouble.

Comment: You have undefined behavior. You never intialize `a` and `b`. Go back to the drawing board and think it all over!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `swap()` function takes pointers, so it needs to be called like `swap(&arr[a], &arr[b]);`.

Otherwise it takes the `int` values as memory adresses (i.e. pointers `int*`) and tries to access them, which leads to a segmentation fault because the program accesses outside of its range of valid addresses.

And for a bubble sort, it would need to iterate through the array multiple times, until all pairs are in the correct order.

Also the variables `a` and `b` are uninitialized.  For bubble sort, it would need to compare-and-swap `i` and `i+1`, for `i` from `0` to `size-2`.